# How to efficiently check records based off a list of prefixes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out a query that will efficiently allow me to check a specific number against a list of prefixes.

My table structure looks like this

Table 1

```
MobileNumber
408726172
307612535
408642517
111824374
```

Table 2

```
Prefix
408
3076
```

Now as you can see some MobileNumber's start with 408 and 307, the Prefix table contains 408 and 3076. Is there a way that I can check for valid prefixes within a SELECT statement without using a loop?

my thoughts would be a SQL query that looks like

```
SELECT MobileNumber FROM Table1 WHERE THE FIRST PART OF THE NUMBER MATCHES ANY OF THE Prefixes in Table2
```

I just can't understand how I can do it

Comment: What data type is `MobileNumber`?

Comment: @dotnetom MobileNumber is a varchar the same with Prefix

Comment: You really should separate these two values instead of fighting your schema like this. Since you have the area code (or prefix) AND the station number in the same column you are violating 1NF by having multiple pieces of data in a single intersection. Split this out and it becomes much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

select all numbers will valid/invalid attribute:

```
select 
  MobileNumber,
  case when exists (select 1 from Table_2 where MobileNumber like Prefix + '%') 
  then 1 else 0 end as IsValid
from Table_1
```

select only valid numbers:

```
select 
MobileNumber
from Table_1
where exists (select 1 from Table_2 where MobileNumber like Prefix + '%')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot on my system and get back to accepting the answer if it works.

Comment: @SandeepBansal, note also that solution with join can return multiple rows for 1 MobileNumber: eg. MobileNumber = 123456, Prefix1 = 12, Prefix2 = 123; output with join MobileNumber = 123456 twice

Answer (score 8):

Something like

```
SELECT Table1.MobileNumber 
  FROM Table1 
         INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.MobileNumber LIKE Table2.Prefix +'%'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot on my system and get back to accepting the answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an alternative way to do this would be like this:

```
SELECT Table1.MobileNumber
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON LEFT(Table1.MobileNumber, LEN(Table2.Prefix)) = Table2.Prefix
```

Comment: It's not always 3 numbers, it could be 4 or even 5 which is demonstrated in my schema above

Comment: I updated the answer based on your response above. Please let me know if this works for you! Thanks!

Comment: If MobileNumber is indexed that one would be out of the game this way. I assume this works but tends to be slow nevertheless.